# Cocos2d-x Android - Google Play Game Services App crashes on connect()

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-x, google-play-services

I tried to implement Google Play Game Services within my Cocos2d-x project based on the baseGameUtils sample project following this description:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/28296

However, the application crashes within the connect() method of the sample file GameHelper.java calling the method

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

The error occurs within the call of the connect() method of the com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, since neither the onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) nor the onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) method gets called.

Logcat shows the following messages:

`W/ActivityManager(  698): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.android.email/.service.AttachmentDownloadService } U=0: not found
W/ActivityManager(  698): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
I/ActivityManager(  698): Config changes=480 {1 0 1.0 262mcc2mnc de_DE ldltr sw360dp w640dp h335dp 480dpi nrml long land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.140}
W/ActivityManager(  698): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10158
W/ActivityManager(  698): mDVFSHelper.release()
I/ActivityManager(  698): Process org.cocos2dx.testcpp (pid 493) (adj 0) has died.`

I guess, that there is something wrong with my AndroidManifest.xml file, but I can not figure out what`s the problem:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".TestCpp"
              android:allowBackup="true"
              android:exported="true"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"/>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need update the lib implementation. I have a template for IOS and Android working with Cocos2d-x and Google Play Game Services.

https://github.com/cpinan/Cocos2dX_GooglePlayGamesServices

You can check this.